# Avoid overriding eloquent data

Tags: laravel

This is my collection of data I need:

```
$author_id = 12345;

$newsTagCollection = NewsTag::
   ->where('author_id', $author_id);
```

```
$postTodaycnt =$newsTagCollection->where('post_date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->get()->count();

$postWeekcnt =$newsTagCollection->where('post_date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->get()->count();

dd($postWeekcnt);

$newsTags = $newsTagCollection->simplePaginate(12);
```

What I'm trying is to avoid calling the Model multiple times and just past post_date on postTodayCount and PostWeekCount. But $postWeekcnt seem to get value same as $postTodaycnt.

How do I not replace the value and get $postTodaycnt, $postWeekcnt and $newsTags value from $newsTagCollection as desired?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.
Answer to that is **Optimization**. Laravel provide [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections) which is very helpful when it comes to such scenarios.

```
// This will return a *Collection* of NewsTag model.
$newsTagCollection = NewsTag::where('author_id', $author_id)->get(); // One query. Use ->get() here to fetch all the data

// Here no new queries will triggered.
$postTodaycnt = $newsTagCollection->where('post_date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->count(); // No need to use get() again
$postWeekcnt =$newsTagCollection->where('post_date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->count();
```